# Disable search on file content

Tags: 2013, search, schema, crawl-rules

I have to refine my search schema to not search for the content of files (e.g. Excel file). I only want it to search for the metadata I have defined for the files.

How do I do this? There are tons of managed and crawled properties. I tried unchecking 'Include in full-text index' on some properties that sound promising, but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this? I need the same...

Comment: No unfortunately I found no of how to do this. Please update here if you ever do. Good luck.

Comment: Might this question already be answered here? [Search Document Properties but not contents](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119724/search-document-properties-but-not-contents)

Comment: i think this is something relevant to you https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/119724/search-document-properties-but-not-contents?noredirect=1&lq=1